# python3 shared memory between lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, copy

Given the following code in python3:

```
>a=[17,[1,'dog'],[bog,5.3]]
>b=a.copy()
```

How `b[1]` is the same as `a[1]` (same position in memory] But how can I change the value of `b[1]` and let that affect `a[1]`?

for example, if I write:

```
b[1]=5
```

that won't affect `a[1]`.
But, I want to change both of them (to make the change affect the shared memory)

Comment: Why use `copy()`? A direct assignment (`b = a`) achieves what you want.

Comment: instead of b = a.copy() do b = a . I'm not sure but I don't think copy() will make 2 objects the same. In fact they are 2 different objects regarding the position in memory

Comment: but when I change a[0] b[0] will change too, which I don't want...

Comment: In other words I want it use copy and find a way to change the value of the "pointer" instead of assigning it a whole new value when I want

Comment: Please read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names1.html, and then see if what you're trying to do still makes sense to yourself. It would also help if you could explain what *problem you hope to solve* by doing this.